# mysql double values checking problem

Tags: mysql, ceil

I wanna make a query that fetches only the rows that has 'cost' value grader than zero.The cost column has double data type.When i write a query like that,

```
select cost from xxx where cost>0;
```

it retrieves the rows only that has value grader than or equal to one.For example it doesnt take like 0.02  or 0.3 values.The query sees these type values as zero.How can i achieve my goal?
Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem using mysql 5.41.

Show us the result of `describe table xxx`;

What happens if you issue the query:

```
select cost from xxx where cost > 0.0;
```

Is your query actually:

```
 select ceil(cost) from xxx where cost > 0.0;
```

If so, for values of cost > 0 but <= 1, you'd get a result set of 1.